# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:countFirebaseDebugDexMethods'

Tags: android, kotlin

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:countFirebaseDebugDexMethods'.

[My Android project](https://github.com/dkrivoruchko/ScreenStream)

When I run this project it occurs an error.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:countFirebaseDebugDexMethods'.
> Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.
```

How can I solve this?

Give a solution.